# variable with block scope - many declaration - standard?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Where does the C standard specify that I cannot declare the same  identifier many times in the same block scope?

Comment: You can always read [the C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html) and look for yourself.

Comment: It is implicit I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some identifiers *can* be redeclared, such as `struct` tags and `extern` objects.  But local variables can't:

```
void bar(void)
{
    int a;
    int a; // constraint violation, 'a' declared a second time
}
```

and that is required by C99 section 6.7 paragraph 3:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier
>   (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except
>   for tags as specified in 6.7.2.3.

This is a "shall" sentence in a "constraints" section, so a program that violates it is ill-formed.

The C standard never uses the term "local variable," but an "identifier [that] has no linkage" is *almost* the same thing.  (You can see that it's not exactly the same thing, or there would be no need to make an exception for tags.)  For the precise definition see section 6.2.2.

(C2011 amends this paragraph slightly, to permit the repetition of `typedef` declarations as well as tags.)

Comment: What do you mean by `"No linkage" means approximately "local variable"`? There's probably a better way of saying that the linker does not deal with local variables if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was searching it a lot.

Comment: @barakmanos `The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than
an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; a block scope
identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.
` so local variable is a part of that.

Comment: So in other words, local variables and static global variables, right?

Comment: no static global variables can never be no linkage identifier they are considered as internal linkage identifier.

Comment: @Sabrina: I'm pretty sure that the compiler can resolve these variable (instead of leaving this to the linker).

Comment: What do you mean ? This is the role of linker not compiler to search for references.

Comment: @barakmanos static variables at file scope have internal linkage (6.2.2/3)

Comment: @barakmanos Did you mean identifiers declared at _block_ scope with the `static` storage-class specifier?  Those indeed have no linkage, if I'm reading 6.2.2 correctly.  At file scope, though, they have internal linkage.  (The C standard never uses the term "global", either.  "External linkage" is the closest approximation.)

Comment: I think the word `static` confused him.

Comment: For example: `static int x` at the file level (outside of any function). Isn't the compiler able to resolve the address of `x` immediately upon processing the given source file?

Comment: what do you man by **file level** ? be more specific please !

Comment: "file scope" and "file level" mean "outside of any function or parameter list"

Comment: @barakmanos `static int x` at "file scope" (*please* use the same terms the standard uses, when talking about the standard!) has _internal_ linkage, which does indeed vaguely mean what you're thinking of when you say "the compiler should be able to resolve the address".  However, the C standard has no concept of a _linker_ either.  The closest it comes is the dividing line between translation phases 7 and 8.

Comment: @barakmanos regarding "resolving the address" , no, e.g. the linker arguments will say what address ranges are available for storing the variable.

Comment: @M.M who told you that he meant file level by file scope ?

Comment: @Sabrina it was obvious to me

Comment: It is obvious. File level / File scope / Global variable. What other interpretation could any of these terms possibly have?

Comment: @barakmanos Well, `static int x;` at file scope does _not_ define what people usually think of as a "global variable"; it's inaccessible from other translation units.

Comment: @zwol: Well it's not a local variable, right? Perhaps local in the file, but not in a function. I use "static" to indicate whether or not it is `static`, and "local/global" to indicate whether it is declared in the scope of a function or in the scope of a file. I thought that was pretty obvious to everyone, but from the comment-thread here, I guess it's not. I suppose that it is partially related to the "ambiguous functionality" of the keyword `static`, when used on a local variable and on a global variable ("local/global" by "my" definition).

Comment: @barakmanos It's not obvious mainly because the C standard carefully avoids using the terms you want to use, in favor of terms like "file scope" and "external/internal linkage", which it gives precise definitions to, with subtle and important differences from the intuitive meanings of the terms you are using.  Please, if you're going to participate in language-lawyering about C at all, read C99 cover to cover (yes, C99, not C2011), familiarize yourself with the standardese terms, and use them.

Comment: "global variable" has several different usages . Personally i do use it for file-scope statics but others don't

Comment: No, I'm not gonna participate in language-lawyering. That's why I chose CS and not Law school...

Comment: Not lawyering at all. Just wondering about the terminology of a few things that (up until now) I assumed to be unequivocal.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the same identifier many times in block scope:

```
int main()
{
    extern int x;
    extern int x;
    extern int x;
}
```

Here we have three declarations of `x` at block scope. This is valid because they all have compatible types (C11 6.7/4) and the same linkage.

I think what you mean to ask is why you cannot **define** the same identifier as a variable many times.  This is covered by C11 6.7/3:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope [...]

The term "no linkage" is covered by the section on linkage, 6.2.2.  Variables defined at block scope have "no linkage" (6.2.2/6). In the previous quote, bear in mind that all definitions are declarations; since it says there cannot be multiple declarations with no linkage it follows that there cannot be multiple definitions.

Comment: I'd use `instantiate` instead of `define`.

Comment: OK, but it might be confused with the preprocessor directive (`#define`) IMO.